# change user email address format only in select

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a query like this:

```
select c.order_id,sum(c.final_for_referraler) as sum,u.email 
from exchaino_app.commissions as c
left join exchaino_app.orders as o on c.order_id = o.id
left join exchaino_app.users as u on c.order_user_id = u.id
group by c.order_id,c.order_user_id;
```

It returns an answer like this :

```
order_id      sum      email
1             10      john@gmail.com
2             11      johnesmit@gmail.com
```

I want to replace the email address with some `*`
it should be return like this:

```
jo**@gmail.com
jo******@gmail.com
```

in query or laravel side without foreach.

Comment: are you using raw query in your laravel?

Comment: I would do this in application code after fetching the plaintext email.

Comment: @sta It doesn't matter, I can use it.

Comment: @HamidNaghipour then I suggest you, use str_replace() or preg_replace() on blade, if you you are not using API response

Comment: @sta thanks. I don't have any blade file and I need it in a API response.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the mysql regexp_replace function. I think you could use that in the query to catch the email address pattern.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace